# In Hive, is there a way to parse multiple occurrences of the same tag within the same XML family?

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, hive, hiveql

In my scenario, there's one occurrence of "Name" tag under each parent family. The parent families repeat, and within each family there are multiple "Value" tags. My expectation is to parse through each [Name, Value] pair and get them displayed row-wise.

Sample XML and the expected output are shown below:

```
<ParentArray>
    <ParentFieldArray>
        <Name>ABCD</Name>
        <Value>
            <string>111</string>
            <string>222</string>
            <string>333</string>
        </Value>
    </ParentFieldArray>
    <ParentFieldArray>
        <Name>EFGH</Name>
        <Value>
            <string>444</string>
            <string>555</string>
        </Value>
    </ParentFieldArray>
</ParentArray>
```

SQL query's output should be:

```
Name         Value
ABCD         111
ABCD         222
ABCD         333
EFGH         444
EFGH         555
```

Here "ParentFieldArray" families repeat, and number of "Value" tags within them too vary, family-wise.

Query attempted:

```
select Name, Value from <table_name> -- "xmlinfo" field in this table includes the above XML content
LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(XPATH(xmlinfo, 'ParentArray/ParentFieldArray/Name/text()')) NM as Name_pos, Name
LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(XPATH(xmlinfo, 'ParentArray/ParentFieldArray/Value/string/text()')) VL as Value_pos, Value;
```

I tried to query with `LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(XPATH(..))` concept, but it doesn't seem to work. Basically I'm **unable to map the right Name against each Value, based on their positions**. This is resulting in cross join.

Is there any other function/concept within SQL that could fetch output as shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Name and pass it to second XPATH to filter only ParentFieldArray containing that Name.

Demo:

```
with your_data as (
select  '<ParentArray>
    <ParentFieldArray>
        <Name>ABCD</Name>
        <Value>
            <string>111</string>
            <string>222</string>
            <string>333</string>
        </Value>
    </ParentFieldArray>
    <ParentFieldArray>
        <Name>EFGH</Name>
        <Value>
            <string>444</string>
            <string>555</string>
        </Value>
    </ParentFieldArray>
</ParentArray>' as xmlinfo
)

select name, value 
  from your_data d
       lateral view outer explode(XPATH(xmlinfo, 'ParentArray/ParentFieldArray/Name/text()')) pf as  Name
       lateral view outer explode(XPATH(xmlinfo, concat('ParentArray/ParentFieldArray[Name="', pf.Name, '"]/Value/string/text()'))) vl as value
```

Result:

```
name    value
ABCD    111
ABCD    222
ABCD    333
EFGH    444
EFGH    555
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance here.. Was basically stuck with retrieving the Name tags & in mapping them individually with their respective Value tags. Cheers!!

Comment: With the above approach, I could resolve for scenarios where there are non-null Value-tags. There are also scenarios with null / empty Value-tags present. Is there a way to read them as well? Suppose in above XML, if there was a <string/> or <string></string> occurrence under Value tag within a ParentFieldArray, is there a way to read those as separate rows where Name will be populated with blank Values?

Comment: @RKR Something like this: 'ParentArray/ParentFieldArray/Value/string/[not text()]'   But i do not  not understand completely. Better ask new question and describe in details the expected output. [not(text())] should help to find such

Comment: I have posted a new question with the details. Kindly have a look at below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65594410/in-hive-how-to-read-through-null-empty-tags-present-within-an-xml-using-explo