# In Hive, how to read through NULL / empty tags present within an XML using explode(XPATH(..)) function?

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, hive, hiveql

In below Hive-query, I need to read the null / empty "string" tags as well, from the XML content. Only the non-null "string" tags are getting considered within the `XPATH()` list now.

```
with your_data as (
select  '<ParentArray>
    <ParentFieldArray>
        <Name>ABCD</Name>
        <Value>
            <string>111</string>
            <string></string>
            <string>222</string>
        </Value>
    </ParentFieldArray>
    <ParentFieldArray>
        <Name>EFGH</Name>
        <Value>
            <string/>
            <string>444</string>
            <string></string>
            <string>555</string>

        </Value>
    </ParentFieldArray>
</ParentArray>' as xmlinfo
)

select Name, Value 
  from your_data d
       lateral view outer explode(XPATH(xmlinfo, 'ParentArray/ParentFieldArray/Name/text()')) pf as  Name
       lateral view outer explode(XPATH(xmlinfo, concat('ParentArray/ParentFieldArray[Name="', pf.Name, '"]/Value/string/text()'))) vl as Value;
```

Expected output from query:

```
Name    Value
ABCD    111
ABCD    
ABCD    222
EFGH    
EFGH    444
EFGH    
EFGH    555
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `XPATH` returns NodeList and if it contains empty node, it is not included in the list.

Concatenation with some string (in XPATH): `concat(/Value/string/text()," ")` does not work here:

> Caused by: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException:
> com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathException: Can not convert
> #STRING to a NodeList!
>
> at
> com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:195)

Easy solution is to replace `<string></string>` and `<string/>` with `<string>NULL</string>` and then you can convert 'NULL' string to null.

Demo:

```
with your_data as (
select  '<ParentArray>
    <ParentFieldArray>
        <Name>ABCD</Name>
        <Value>
            <string>111</string>
            <string></string>
            <string>222</string>
        </Value>
    </ParentFieldArray>
    <ParentFieldArray>
        <Name>EFGH</Name>
        <Value>
            <string/>
            <string>444</string>
            <string></string>
            <string>555</string>
        </Value>
    </ParentFieldArray>
</ParentArray>' as xmlinfo
)

select name, case when value='NULL' then null else value end value
  from (select regexp_replace(xmlinfo,'<string></string>|<string/>','<string>NULL</string>') xmlinfo 
          from your_data d
       ) d
       lateral view outer explode(XPATH(xmlinfo, 'ParentArray/ParentFieldArray/Name/text()')) pf as  Name
       lateral view outer explode(XPATH(xmlinfo, concat('ParentArray/ParentFieldArray[Name="', pf.Name, '"]/Value/string/text()'))) vl as value
```

Result:

```
name    value
ABCD    111
ABCD    
ABCD    222
EFGH    
EFGH    444
EFGH    
EFGH    555
```

Comment: Hi, could you also please look into a similar scenario explained in below link?  @leftjoin 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66580649/in-hive-how-to-explode-child-tags-under-identical-parent-tags-present-within-an

Comment: @RKR okay, Answered