# In Hive, how to explode same child-tags under the same parent-tags appearing multiple times within an XML?

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, hive, hiveql

In below Hive-query, the XML consists of *Parents* tag with 4 *Parent* families and 4 *ParentArray* families within. Under each *ParentArray*, there are *ParentFieldArray* occurrences consisting of the same Name and Value tags (**ABCD** and **111** resp.).

```
with your_data as (
select  '<Parents>
    <Parent>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentFieldArray>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>
                    <string>111</string>
                </Value>
            </ParentFieldArray>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentFieldArray>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>
                    <string>111</string>
                </Value>
            </ParentFieldArray>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentFieldArray>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>
                    <string>111</string>
                </Value>
            </ParentFieldArray>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentFieldArray>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>
                    <string>111</string>
                </Value>
            </ParentFieldArray>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
</Parents>' as xmlinfo
)
select name, pos+1 as pos, value
  from your_data d
       lateral view outer posexplode(XPATH(xmlinfo, 'Parents/Parent/ParentArray/ParentFieldArray/Name/text()')) pf as  pos, Name
       lateral view outer explode(XPATH(xmlinfo, concat('Parents/Parent/ParentArray/ParentFieldArray[',pf.pos+1, '][Name="', pf.Name, '"]/Value/string/text()'))) vl as value;
```

The above query is populating all "111" rows under 1st index itself and NULL values under indices 2, 3 and 4.

Expected output from query:

```
name    pos value
ABCD    1   111
ABCD    2   111
ABCD    3   111
ABCD    4   111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in XPATH. [] takes precedence and producing weird results. Use brackets.

```
with your_data as (
select  '<Parents>
    <Parent>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentFieldArray>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>
                    <string>111</string>
                </Value>
            </ParentFieldArray>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentFieldArray>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>
                    <string>111</string>
                </Value>
            </ParentFieldArray>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentFieldArray>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>
                    <string>111</string>
                </Value>
            </ParentFieldArray>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentFieldArray>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>
                    <string>111</string>
                </Value>
            </ParentFieldArray>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
</Parents>' as xmlinfo
)
select  pos+1 as pos, Name, Value
  from your_data d
       lateral view outer posexplode(XPATH(xmlinfo, 'Parents/Parent/ParentArray/ParentFieldArray/Name/text()')) pf as  pos, Name
       lateral view outer explode(XPATH(xmlinfo, concat('((Parents/Parent/ParentArray/ParentFieldArray)[',pf.pos+1, '])[Name="', pf.Name, '"]/Value/string/text()'))) vl as value
      ;
```

Result:

```
pos name    value
1   ABCD    111
2   ABCD    111
3   ABCD    111
4   ABCD    111
```