# In Hive, how to explode tags in an XML within subfamilies & outside subfamilies and map them appropriately familywise?

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, hive, hiveql

In the below XML provided, I need to explode {Name, Value} pairs along with ParentID tags and map them appropriately, "Parent" familywise:

```
<Parents>
    <Parent>
        <ParentID>12345</ParentID>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>111</Value>
            </ParentField>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentID>54321</ParentID>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>111</Value>
            </ParentField>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>CDBA</Name>
                <Value>222</Value>
            </ParentField>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentID>12534</ParentID>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>111</Value>
            </ParentField>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>222</Value>
            </ParentField>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>CDBA</Name>
                <Value>333</Value>
            </ParentField>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentID>51342</ParentID>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>111</Value>
            </ParentField>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>222</Value>
            </ParentField>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>333</Value>
            </ParentField>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>CDBA</Name>
                <Value>444</Value>
            </ParentField>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
</Parents>
```

Expected output:

```
ParentID    Name    Value
12345       ABCD    111
54321       ABCD    111
54321       CDBA    222
12534       ABCD    111
12534       ABCD    222
12534       CDBA    333
51342       ABCD    111
51342       ABCD    222
51342       ABCD    333
51342       CDBA    444
```

In every Parent family, there's a ParentID tag. Also in ParentArray subfamily, there are multiple ParentField subfamilies with {Name, Value} pairs present. Need to get ParentID's mapped correctly with their {Name, Value} pairs, within each Parent family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine XPATH filtering by values and positions in arrays. See comments in the code:

```
with your_data as (
    select  '<Parents>
    <Parent>
        <ParentID>12345</ParentID>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>111</Value>
            </ParentField>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentID>54321</ParentID>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>111</Value>
            </ParentField>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>CDBA</Name>
                <Value>222</Value>
            </ParentField>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentID>12534</ParentID>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>111</Value>
            </ParentField>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>222</Value>
            </ParentField>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>CDBA</Name>
                <Value>333</Value>
            </ParentField>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentID>51342</ParentID>
        <ParentArray>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>111</Value>
            </ParentField>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>222</Value>
            </ParentField>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>ABCD</Name>
                <Value>333</Value>
            </ParentField>
            <ParentField>
                <Name>CDBA</Name>
                <Value>444</Value>
            </ParentField>
        </ParentArray>
    </Parent>
</Parents>
' as xmlinfo
)

select p.parentid, n.name, -- n.pos+1, 
       --filter by parentid, name and position and extract scalar
       XPATH_STRING(xmlinfo,concat('(((Parents/Parent)[ParentID="',p.parentid,'"])/ParentArray/ParentField[',n.pos+1,'])[Name="',n.name,'"]/Value/text()')) as value 
 from your_data d
      lateral view explode(XPATH(xmlinfo, 'Parents/Parent/ParentID/text()')) p as parentid
       --filer by parentID to get array of Name with position inside ParentArray 
      lateral view posexplode(XPATH(xmlinfo, concat('(Parents/Parent)[ParentID="',p.parentid,'"]/ParentArray/ParentField/Name/text()'))) n as pos, name
;
```

Result:

```
p.parentid  n.name  value
12345   ABCD    111
54321   ABCD    111
54321   CDBA    222
12534   ABCD    111
12534   ABCD    222
12534   CDBA    333
51342   ABCD    111
51342   ABCD    222
51342   ABCD    333
51342   CDBA    444
```